# Using Root-Relative Links With Subdomain

Tags: html, relative-path

I have inherited a website where the previous developer has coded all links relative to the site root, with a leading backslash in each link:

```
<link href="/css/file.css" />
<script src="/js/file.js"></script>
```

This works great for when the site is hosted on a server, as the links will equate to:

```
http://www.example.com/css/file.css
http://www.example.com/js/file.js
```

However, I'm trying to get these links to work correctly when called from within a **subfolder** for local testing. Specifically, I'm using WAMP, and have moved the entire code to a local folder called `site` at `http://localhost:8080/site/`.

I can't use the root of `localhost`, as WAMP stores various files there (including an index that would get overwritten).

The obvious solution, as many posts here on StackOverflow suggest, is to simply use folder-relative links, such as:

```
<link href="css/file.css" />
<script src="js/file.js"></script>
```

However, there are literally *hundreds* of hard-coded root-relative links in various different files, so it would be great having to avoid altering every single one of them if possible.

To avoid having to edit every link, I've tried setting an HTML `<base>` tag and specifying the folder directly:

```
<base href="http://localhost:8080/site/">
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.

Is `<base>` incompatible with root-relative links?

Is there any way I can easily have all files reference `http://localhost:8080/site/` without having to manually edit each one of their preexisting root-relative links? Or will I have to manually update each one to be folder-relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is `<base>` incompatible with root-relative links?

No, but an absolute path is still an absolute path. It will resolve relative to `http://localhost:8080/site/` by dropping `/site/`.

If you want to use absolute paths and not keep your development sites in subdirectories, then [configure your HTTP server to use Virtual Name Hosting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html).

Add custom hostnames (either in the DNS server for your LAN or in the `hosts` file on your development system), such as `site.localhost`, and set the `DocumentRoot` in a virtual host.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that's there an option that allows me to keep root-relative links -- it certainly seems the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the replace function in your IDE? You can simply replace all the `="/` with `="`. It'll save you a lot of work and stress.