# Relative path without current directory

Tags: html, linux, google-chrome, firefox

Hello everyone i have an html file with the following tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/css/classic.css">
```

the problem is when i open the file in the browser it complain about not finding the classic.css file,but when adding the current directory to the beginning of the href:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./lib/css/classic.css">
```

It just works, and to make it worse i have bunch of similar files each one with tens of these relative paths how i can resolve this problem?

Comment: what is your base href? maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Are you trying to load the **same** CSS file into multiple HTML files? If so, you'll want a root-relative (or absolute) path like the first link you posted. What is your root folder? Assuming you have `site.com/lib/css`, `/lib/css/classic.css` will work from whichever file you call it from. If you want to load **different** CSS files for each HTML file, you'll need to list the relationship between each.

Comment: The base directory is /var/www/my_project/public/

Comment: It sounds like your `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/my_project/public`. In that case, `/lib/css/classic.css` as a `<link>` should work from any file inside of `public`. It may be a good idea to use the `F12 Debugger` console window to find out exactly where your CSS file is trying to get loaded from. Don't forget you can use `../` if you need to 'break out' and go up one folder.

Comment: Hello Obsidian Age thank you for your comments the browser is trying to get the Css file starting from the root directory This is from my console:
    GET file:///lib/css/classic.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, this is very similar to **[the first question I asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41969079/using-root-relative-links-with-subdomain)**.

You're working from `localhost` at the moment, so CSS files are loaded from the `file://` protocol. When you move your code to a hosted website, the links will automatically resolve for you with the root-relative prefix (`/`).

In order to get them working on `localhost`, you have a number of options:

- Make use of subdomains. The root is considered to be the root of the subdomain. That is to say, `site.localhost` will resolve the links `/lib/css/classic.css` (though `localhost/site` will not). In this case you'll need to configure your server to use **[Virtual Name Hosting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html)**.
- Make use of a relative `<link>`, using `../` to traverse up. This could look like: 
  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="current/../lib/css/style.css" />`
- Simply use a large number of traversals, to make sure you hit the document root, and work from there:
  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../../lib/css/style.css" />`
- Set a **[`<base>` URL](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-set-relative-urls-with-the-base-tag--cms-21399)** and use relative links from that:
  `<base href="/lib/css">`
  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />`

I'd recommend using the fourth option myself, though it may take a little tweaking.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful i really do appreciate your answer